# Deriving the partial fraction decomposition of a hypergeometric function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, partial-fractions

I am studying a research paper and I don't understand how to derive a partial fraction representation of algebraic expressions whose image I am posting here.

> **Démonstration**
>
> On écrit $$R_n(t)(t+j)^a =F(t)^3\times G(t)^3 \times H(t)^{a-6} \times I(t)$$
>   ou $I(t)=t+\frac{n}{2}$ et $$
> F(t)=\frac{(t-n)_n}{(t)_{n+1}}(t+j), \quad 
> G(t)=\frac{(t+n+1)_n}{(t)_{n+1}}(t+j), \quad 
> H(t)=\frac{n!}{(t)_{n+1}}(t+j).
> $$
>   Décomposons $F(t), G(t)$, et $H(t)$ en fractions partielles :$$
> F(t)=1+\sum_{p=0\\p\neq j}^n\frac{j-p}{t+p}f_p, \quad
> G(t)=1+\sum_{p=0\\p\neq j}^n\frac{j-p}{t+p}g_p, \quad
> H(t)=\sum_{p=0\\p\neq j}^n\frac{j-p}{t+p}h_p, \quad 
> $$

Can someone please derive one of the $F(t)$ , $G(t)$ and $H(t)$ and tell a reference for studying more about how to obtain such representation. 
I will be really thankful for the help.

> Edit 1 [image]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Comment: @Brian thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $(t)_n$? Are the $f_p, g_p, h_p$ just numeric coefficients?

Comment: @quarague $ (t)_n $ is pochhammer symbol , $ (t)_n$ = t(t+1) ... (t+n-1) and in case $f_p$ , $g_p$, $ h_p$ is needed see edit.

Comment: @Dxdxdade,  just to clarify - do you need to prove that two different representation of $F(t)$s (using the sum of weighted $f_n$'s and pochhammer symbols) are equal, and same for two representations of $G(t)$ and $H(t)$?

Comment: @Yulia V, I am given F(t) =$\frac { (t-n)_n }{ (t)_{n+1}} $ (t+j) and I need to prove F(t) = 1+ $\sum_{p=0}^n \frac{j-p} { t+p}  f_p$ . I hope it's fine now.

Comment: @Dxdxdade almost :) what's $j$?

Comment: @Yulia V assume j to be any constant. I am sorry I slept as there was night time in my area and then went to attend class.

Comment: @Yulia V assume first 4 lines of  highlighted part 1 to be true . The aim is to rewrite F(t) , G(t) as it is given in 2nd last line. I am really sorry that question was not as clear as it should be although I thought I asked clearly and I could not comment yesterday as I use MSE on browser in Android and so don't get any notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we derive the partial  fraction decomposition of $F(t)$. The other  functions can be transformed similarly.

We  have
\begin{align*}
F(t)&=\frac{(t-n)_n}{(t)_{n+1}}(t+j)\\
&=\frac{(t-1)(t-2)\cdots(t-n)}{t(t+1)\cdots(t+n)}(t+j)\\
&=\color{blue}{\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n(t-k)}{\prod_{l=0}^n(t+l)}(t+j)=\sum_{{q=0}\atop{q\ne  j}}^n\frac{\alpha_q}{t+q}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We see  the left-hand side of  (1)   is a rational  function in $t$ with denominator  $\prod_{{l=0}\atop{t\ne j}}^n(t+l)$ which      is a    polynomial  of   degree   $n$  with  simple   zeros at  integral  values  $0\leq  p\leq   n$,  $p\ne  j$.

We write   the left-hand side in (1) as partial fraction decomposition with  unknown constants $\alpha_q$, $0\leq q\leq n$, $q\ne j$.

> We determine the unknown constants $\alpha_q$  as follows.  We consider  $0\leq p\leq   n$, $p\ne j$ and multiply  (1) with $t+p$. We obtain 
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n(t-k)}{\prod_{{l=0}\atop{t\ne p}}^n(t+l)}(t+j)=\sum_{{q=0}\atop{q\ne  j, q\ne p}}^n\frac{\alpha_q}{t+q}(t+p)+\alpha_p\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Note the summand $\alpha_p$ is separated from the sum of the right-hand side, since this is the term where $t+p$ cancels.

> We *evaluate* (2) at $t=-p$ and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n(-p-k)}{\prod_{{l=0}\atop{l\ne p}}^n(-p+l)}(-p+j)=\alpha_p\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since the numerator at the left-hand side of (3) is
>   \begin{align*}
> \prod_{k=1}^n(-p-k)=(-p-1)(-p-2)\cdots(-p-n)=(-p-n)_{n}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>   we obtain from (1), (3) and (4)
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n(t-k)}{\prod_{l=0}^n(t+l)}(t+j)&=\sum_{{p=0}\atop{p\ne  j}}^n\frac{\alpha_p}{t+p}\\
> &=\sum_{{p=0}\atop{p\ne  j}}^n\frac{j-p}{t+p}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{(-p-n)_{n}}{\prod_{{l=0}\atop{l\ne p}}^n(-p+l)}}_{f_p}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

Comment: can you please have a look at this question also if you have some time to spare.I am not finding a way out. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3543021/unable-to-think-how-to-prove-a-result-in-a-research-paper-of-wadim-zudililin-and

Comment: @Dxdxdade: Many thanks for accepting the answer and granting the bounty. With respect to your other question, I'm sorry, but I do not have a solution at hand.